# Why can't I get data from USB-A to USB-C port?

Tags: usb, usb-c

I am having trouble achieving data communication when using a USB-A to USB-C cable.

I have a mouse with a USB-A plug and I need to connect this via a USB-A socket/socket coupler (a panel mount connector). If I then use a ***USB-A plug to USB-A plug*** cable, the mouse works correctly on my laptop (USB-A socket).

However, I need to be able to use this on the laptop's USB-C socket. If I plug the mouse into the coupler and then use a ***USB-A plug to USB-C plug*** cable, the mouse is not seen on the laptop's USB-C socket, nor do the mouse's lights turn on.

The USB-A to USB-C cables that I have tried have been phone charger cables, so I initially thought that they may not offer data transfer. However, if I plug a phone (USB-C) into the laptops USB-A socket using the same cable, I can transfer data, so that does not seem to be the problem. It is just that the cables don't seem to be able to transfer data if the USB-C end is plugged into the laptop, only the USB-A end will work at the laptop.

Is there a reason that I can't get transfer to work with the USB-C end at the laptop? Is this a host/peripheral issue? Do some cables only work in one direction? Is it a USB-A/USB-C compatibility issue? A USB revision compatibility issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This *can* work. However I think the issue is the cable you are using does not have terminating resistors that are needed to work in the "reverse" direction.

A USB-A to USB-C cable with a male USB A connector will work for charging/data for a USB-C device (phone). But usually doesn't work for attaching USB-A devices to a USB-C host (laptop) as they lack the termination resistors required on CC pins.

You need a USB-C to USB-A female cable/dongle that has terminating resistors to get this to work.

Quick reference for you to read is the Wikipedia entry on USB-C https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB-C

Comment: When I first thought about the "reverse direction", I thought about how when my USB-C phone is connected to the laptop's USB-A port I can send files from the laptop to the phone and download phone files to the laptop. That made me think that data is going both ways. Is that an oversimplification, and not quite what you mean by reverse direction?

Comment: To answer my own comment above, it was an oversimplification. I was able to achieve bi-directional data transfer with the phone because the laptop's USB-A port knows that it is the host, and therefore doesn't need to rely on the CC in the USB-C plug to tell it that it is safe to connect Vbus. Neither the phone nor laptop's USB-C port would not be able to act as host with this cable because it lacks the pull-down resistor on the configuration channel of the USB-C plug, which is needed for a USB-C host to activate the Vbus pin.

Comment: Correct! That's exactly the issue. Sorry I couldn't answer faster, timezones are fun.

Please accept my answer if it was helpful